# Clashing rules in .htacess throwing an internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

I'm trying to remap old images paths to new ones, on a site that's built with Codeigniter.

Old paths look like this:

`mydomain.com/images/maps/MI/206717178X.jpg`

and new paths look like this:

`mydomain.com/resources/images/products/front/MI/206717178X.jpg`

This is my .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^images/maps/([A-Z]{2,3})/(.*)$ resources/images/products/front/$1/$2 [L]
 RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And I'm getting `Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

If I remove the last line, the remapping works well, but of course, the whole website doesn't work, because it needs the index.php in all the urls...

So there seems to be a clashing between the last line and the remapping line, but I don't know what it is. Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` only applies to very next `RewriteRule`. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip files/directories from all the rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^images/maps/([A-Z]{2,3})/(.*)$ resources/images/products/front/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php/$0 [L]
```